# Can I share files between my Macbook Air and my Windows 10 PC with a usb-c adapter?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, filesystem

I am trying to edit high-quality YouTube videos using iMovie on my Mac. However, it does not have enough space to export the video. So I tried connecting my Mac to my PC using a usb cable and a usb-c adapter. Strangely, it showed in the file system, but the files weren't showing, the computer was named "New Volume," and when I tried exporting, it said "Could not create a file." Can I somehow connect my MacBook Air to my PC, even if all the MacBook has is a usb-c port? I did use a usb from a portable hard drive, but it should've worked fine, since my PC showed up in the file system, but as new volume instead of its name. How do I fix this if there is a way to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think PC work in target disk mode so what you’re looking for is a network to enable file sharing from the Windows PC.

Once Windows shares a folder via SMB connect from the Mac.

- https://mashtips.com/transfer-files-between-pc-and-mac/

You want proper two way sharing to export and place more than one file.  Many online guides are more for bulk transfer of all data once. For your case, durable sharing is the way to go.

Or get a USB external drive to export the files. That is simple and portable and cheap. Relocating files so you have enough working free space is the power move here for efficiency. Store primary material and archival footage elsewhere so you can use your fast internal storage for the primary job is my best advice.

Comment: I tried an external usb hard drive, but it also said failed to make file. But strangely, it actually had the right name for the hard drive. I would've used Google Drive if I could but iMovie has no option to export to google drive and the downloads don't fully download sometimes anyway.

Comment: I think I figured out a solution to my problem. I think I could export the video in small chunks, upload them to Google Drive, delete them, and repeat until my whole video is on google drive. Then I could go into Windows Video Editor from my PC and export from there. Does that sound like a good idea?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of work. Sharing folders via SMB is very simple, then just make sure you're on the same network (in home networks, you can even mix and match ethernet and wifi if you don't have an Ethernet adapter for your Mac. Some - but not all - corporate networks don't allow that), and you'll be able to just open the PC as a folder on your Mac and drop the files there.

Comment: The issue with exporting multiple file chunks, beyond being a massive hassle, is that you will lose a lot of quality from encoding the video twice (once to generate the segments, then once again to generate the stitched result), unless you use some specialized tool that allows merging video streams directly but it's even more hassle on top and could be challenging for a casual use.

Comment: Well said @Kroltan - the OP is looking for a sub optimal temporary workaround, so I’ll add that last as a longer term, optimal solution to avoid the “problem” being asked directly.